# RegEx not working in Google Analyitcs

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have a webpages in different languages, the webpages have this structure 
https://brussel.iticketsro.com/Munt/fr-FR/shows/pinocchio/events

variables are

a) group 1: fr-FR | nl-NL | nl-BE | .*

b) group 2:pinocchio/events can be a number of other things.

So, my RegEx is:

```
^https:\/\/brussel\.iticketsro\.com\/Munt\/(.*)shows\/(.*)$
```

But this won't work when I input it in GA. And I can't figure out why.

Comment: Try `^Munt/([^/]*)/shows/(.*)`

Comment: `Munt/([^/]*)/shows/(.*)` seems to work, when i drop the "^". I don't really see the logic behind this, but all well ends well. Thanks!

Comment: That means the `Munt` is not the starting text in the input. I suppose the `/` before `Munt` must be used for safety. See my answer, and if it works, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may use

```
/Munt/([^/]*)/shows/(.*)
```

**Details**:

- `/Munt/` - a literal substring
- `([^/]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `/`
- `/shows/`  - a literal substring
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VWdr0W/1) (just showing what texts are captured into groups).